# How to resync audio and video in an avi file

Tags: video, audio, video-conversion

I have a file where the audio and video are out of sync. I know that there are some media players that allow you to shift the audio so that you can manually put it in sync with the video. However, I want to fix the file so that this does not have to be done. What programs can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways:

1. Of this happens when audio and video are converted simultaneously in a converter program. If this is the result of a video you converted, Reconvert it from the original... but this time demux the audio, convert it separately into desired format (mp3, aac, etc), then convert your video, then remux the two files. Which program you use depends on the filetype. Something like Virtualdub and Virtualdubmod can do it under the audio streams/compression section (there's a save WAV button)
2. If the file is an mkv, you're in luck. MKVtoolnix has a section where you can stretch the audio, delay it so it starts playing later (or sooner), etc. You then save your mkv and it's pretty much an instant fix without the need to re-encode anything. Get the GUI for the program to make life easier.
3. You can extract the audio, without re-encoding it, and then just chop off the end (or add some dead silence at the beginning) with an audio editing program such as cooledit. Then remux the adjusted audio with the video.